# How to find the tex encoding of specific fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

While encoding for common fonts is easy to find, encoding for less common ones are fairly hard to obtain. I know that the encoding for `cmr` is `OT1` and the encoding for `cmmi` is `OML`. However I can't find the encoding for `cmcsc` and `cmtt`. Are they `OT1` or some variant of it? In general how can I find the encoding for any font?

Answer (score 9):

You're taking the wrong approach.

The original Computer Modern fonts have *ad hoc* encodings devised by Knuth in order to fit as many glyphs as possible in 128 slot fonts.

When Rainer Schöpf and Frank Mittelbach released the New Font Selection Scheme version 2 (NFSS2), they introduced the notion of “output encoding”, so creating the now familiar OT1, OML, OMS and OMX encodings, along with T1.

The last one is a *real* encoding for 256 slot fonts. It was agreed upon at the 1990 TUG meeting in Cork, Ireland, in order to cover a large number of European languages. This had become possible by the introduction of *virtual fonts*, which allow to remap and merge existing fonts into a consistent layout.

The (pseudo)encoding OT1 is just a portmanteau. For instance, `cmr10` has ¡ and ¿ where `cmtt10` has < and >, but both are “OT1-encoded”. Also `cmti10` is OT1-encoded, but it has *£* where `cmr10` has $.

The question “what encoding is `cmcsc10`” is ill-posed. It is what it is and it is assigned in LaTeX to OT1. Two OT1-encoded fonts have corresponding glyphs in most slots, but may differ as shown above in some places.